# Only allowing a single touchesMoved method triggered per period of time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, touchesmoved

I am using `touchesMoved` with a coordinate system to detect and respond to user touches within certain areas of the screen. For example, if I have a virtual keyboard and the user swipes across the keys, it reads the coordinates and responds:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch * touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    if(point.y < 333 && point.y > 166 && point.x < 90 && point.x > 20)
    {
       //do something
    }
}
```

...However, the problem is, if the user slowly drags across the keys, or the border between keys, the method is triggered several times in a row, playing the piano key sound in a stutter.

How can I prevent this stutter? I think setting a minimum delay of 0.25 seconds between each successive if statement triggering would help. Also, this delay would only be for a specific if statement -- I want the user to be able to drag across the keys quickly and trigger different key's if-statement as quick as they want.

Does anyone know how to code something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
BOOL _justPressed; // Declare this in your @interface

...

- (void)unsetJustPressed {
    _justPressed = NO;
}
```

Then, in your `touchesMoved`:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (_justPressed) {
        // A key was just pressed, so do nothing.
        return;
    }
    else {
        _justPressed = YES;

        // Do stuff here

        [self performSelector:@selector(unsetJustPressed)
                   withObject:nil
                   afterDelay:0.25];
    }
}
```

This way, you set a variable `_justPressed` to `YES` every `touchesMoved:withEvent:` is called (or within a specific conditional in there, depending on what you want to do), and you use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` to set `_justPressed` to `NO` after a certain time period, and so you can just check whether `_justPressed` is `YES` when `touchesMoved:` is called to ascertain whether it was called recently.

Remember, you don't have to return from the method like in the example above, you can simply use `_justPressed` to check whether you should play the sound, but still perform your other actions. The example is just to give you a basic idea of what to do.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed answer, it really helped solve my question!